# WMTS with Mapbox WebGL

Tags: wmts, mapbox-gl

I need to add a WMTS to a mapping application that uses mapbox-webgl (this is a React App using [react-map-gl](https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl)).  There is no support for WMTS in mapbox-webgl but it seems like I should be able to do the math in the client to convert the map coordinates to a corresponding tile.

I can get the service GetCapabilities via fetch and have the map coordinates and zoom available via viewport.

Assuming I fetch the GetCapabilities on componentDidMount and set them to state.  How do I convert the map zoom and coordinates to a corresponding tileMatrix, Rox, and Column?

```
let zoom = this.state.viewport.zoom
let lat = this.state.viewport.latitude
let lon = this.state.viewport.longitude
let getCapabilities =  this.state.getCapabilities
```

Comment: the short answer is yes, please take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and find out why asking yes/no questions is not the best plan around here.

Comment: original question has been reworded to fit this site's scope.